# Hover over link, image appears loop

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm currently building a site for a gallery. I have a table of exhibitions in a simple list format, and what I'm after is when the user hovers over a title of an exhibition, a preview image appears, and when you hover off it disappears.

I'm using Wordpress and I have all the core structure in place:

I have my table
I have one single image displayed, absolutely and set to display none
I have added unique post classes to both the title of the exhibition and the image

I just can't seem to link it both up.

This is my jQuery so far with what I thought would work:

```
$('table#archive-table td a').hover(
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    function () {
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.'className).fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function () {
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.'className).fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

Example HTML:

```
<a class="33" href="#">Palomar</a>
<div class="first-show-image 33">
  <div class="grid_2">
    <img src="test.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<a class="48" href="#">Palomar #2</a>
<div class="first-show-image 48">
  <div class="grid_2">
    <img src="test.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers,
R

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is that you are experiencing.

Comment: did you type the example code wrong for the hover code?  I have never seen a variable defined in that manner...

Comment: Sorry. If you hover over the anchor with a class '33', for example, the div with the class '33' would fade in. If you remove the hover, it fades out. And so forth...

Comment: Have you tried writing this `var className = $(this).attr('class');` inside the hovering functions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how closely your example code matches the real code, but there's an error in the javascript. Try this

```
$('table#archive-table td a').hover(
    function () {
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function () {
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table#archive-table td a').hover(
    function () {
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.' + className).fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function () {
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        $('body.archive .first-show-image.' + className).fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

Comment: This is what worked. A combination of @Klors and JEES — thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are defining a variable where jquery is expecting funcitons. try this:

```
 $('table#archive-table td a').hover(
        function () {
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
            $('body.archive .first-show-image.'className).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function () {
         var className = $(this).attr('class');
            $('body.archive .first-show-image.'className).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );
```